# Python2 - proc.stdin not passing password correctly to easyrsa

Tags: python-2.7, openvpn

The idea to revoke users from the VPN, with an `easyrsa` command. Manually this works. However, when I perform this action with Python it fails.

The `easyrsa` command asks for 2 arguments, the first one is to continue, the second one is a password.

My current code is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

pass_phrase = "damn_good_password"
proc = Popen(['/usr/local/share/easy-rsa/easyrsa', 'revoke', 'user@somewhere.com'], stdin=PIPE)

time.sleep(1)

proc.stdin.write('yes\n')
proc.stdin.flush()

time.sleep(1)

proc.stdin.write(pass_phrase + "\n")
proc.stdin.flush()
```

The script outputs the following:

```
user@vpn $ sudo ./test.py
Type the word 'yes' to continue, or any other input to abort.
  Continue with revocation: Using configuration from /usr/local/share/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.cnf
Enter pass phrase for /etc/openvpn/pki/private/ca.key:
user@vpn $
User interface error
unable to load CA private key
5283368706004:error:0907B068:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:bad password read:pem_pkey.c:117:
```

I think Python incorrectly passes the password to the process. When performing these steps manually and copying the password, it works.

Can someone point me in the right direction to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps the underlying openssl call is not expecting the password on stdin? Just a guess, I don't know where you'd go from there, other than poking through the easyrsa code to find the command and troubleshooting from there.

Comment: ah okay, I thought it was a Python related issue. Thx